# How often is didReceiveMemoryWarning called?

Tags: ios, memory-management

Let's say your iPhone has low memory and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called. Your app then releases SOME (not all) images from the cache, but is still taking too much memory. Is `didReceiveMemoryWarning` then called again and again if you release some more memory but still not enough? Or is your app just terminated after one warning?

Comment: I would say you get the warning every time you try to allocate new memory.

Comment: didReceiveMemory is called many times till it reaches the limit and finally terminates the app

Comment: It's called as often as iOS wants it to be called.  Apple doesn't publish the algorithm, as far as I know.

Comment: when there is too much of memory being used and it is not deallocated properly, you will recieve the memory warning!!! If it continues, and memory still kept on increasing, the app terminates, and again the method is called!!!